# Setting Custom Property of SharePoint WP readonly

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-enterprise, web-part-property

How to set the custom property(bool) of sharepoint 2010 custom webpart as read Only based on a condition?

Comment: related: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/12731/read-only-column-in-a-sharepoint-list

Comment: hi mike - thanks for the link but i am not sure how it is related to it

Comment: I misinterpreted the question there, sorry.

Comment: In general you use ReadOnly(true) attribute for the purpose but as you mentioned based on a condition, can you shed some light on it?

Comment: Hi Diptarang, thanks for the reply - based on other bool property the current property should be read-Only.