# Creating a column that can only be modified by a group of people

Tags: security, column, access, read-only

I am creating a simple list (imagine a request for instance) in Sharepoint.
This list can be modified by the user, but the field "Status" (Approved, rejected, waiting, -And any status I could imagine) can only be modified by the group of manager.

After searching a lot of on the web, I understood that "read-only" is not so easy out of the box in Sharepoint.

So, after reading this link ([Read-only column in a SharePoint list](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/12731/read-only-column-in-a-sharepoint-list)) I tried to create a lookup to a second list that is only the manager can edit/write, and used a lookup.

Unfortunately, after some tests, the user is still able to modify this field.

Is that a correct approach, or I am doing something wrong?

I hope my question is clear, because that sounds like a basic feature.

Answer (score 0):

For the example you give, there is built in functionality to "Require content approval", that you can access from the versioning settings page off of list/library settings. For more general functionality of that type, I believe it can be implemented as a workflow.