# 2010 read only column datasheet view

Tags: 2010

I am using 2010 SharePoint and I need to make 3 out of my 7 columns in datasheet view 'read only'. How do I do it?

I have tried several solutions:
- Creating a InfoPath form
- Hiding columns, etc

Answer (score 0):

Try the answer to this [question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/12731/read-only-column-in-a-sharepoint-list).  The premise is that the read-only columns are lookups to a different list with restricted permission.  It doesn't go into detail, but I imagine each has a duplicate field that is filled in on item creation.  Then a workflow runs only on item creation to write it to the 2nd list.  Any further changes to the field are moot and the lookup column shows the original data.  Just spitballin'.